# Python sqlalchemy strugles when mysql query result is empty

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

Hi I am running mysql queries from within Python Pandas.

I have a large table 50mil records I am querying using a for loop. The for loop is cycling through a large list of customer ids (some 20,000) I need a single return each for. The loop enables me to clean up the mysql results and return a single result per customer, as in this table a customer can have multiple records within the date range criteria set.

I am seeking to return the closest record to the end date for each customer. What I am looking through are purchase actions so I can not look for an exact date and time as not all customers purchase items on every day at every time. Thus I am using a wider Date range, sorting by newest date and limiting the return to 1. This should give me a record for each customer, on the desired date or back in time to the closest date a purchase was recorded.

I am also opening and closing the database connection on each loop as I was finding if the MYSQL connector paused for whatever reason the query would hang in python for up to 48 hours before erroring in a time out. I am using the try.except function to manage the timeout errors this process will throw up.

The issue I am now facing and that I am struggling to find an answer for is when a mysql query results in an empty object. Pandas is continuing to wait for data, and as such pauses indefinitely.

I am thinking sqlachemy.engine.Result.one_or_none() should handle these circumstances and cause a time out the except layer of the try catch will manage. But I can not find an example that suits my circumstances. Or any other way to wait a sensible amount of time (eg 5 minutes), then force a timeout error the try.except can catch and manage. thus allowing the for loop to continue on without getting bogged down with these empty results.

Therefore I am seeking the communities help.

here is the block of code I have working but which I am struggling to find a solution for.

```
customer_price_at_date = pd.DataFrame()

startDate = '2020-02-11'
endDate = '2020-02-28'

count = 0
loop_len = len(customers_df.index)

for index, row in customers_df.itterows():
   db_connection = engine.connect()

   try:
     customer_id = row('id')
     customer_purchase_query = ("SELECT customerId, purchasePrice, orderPrice, orderDate "\
                                "FROM orders WHERE customerId = {0} AND orderDate BETWEEN '{1}'"\
                                "AND '{2}' ORDER BY customerId DESC LIMIT 1"\
                                 ).format(customer_id, startDate, endDate)

   customer_price_at_date = customer_price_at_date.append(pd.readsql(customer_purchase_query, 
                            con=db_connection))

   db_connection.close()
   count = count + 1
   loop_len = loop_len -1

   print('Processing Customer Id ' + str(customer_id) + ' in loop ' + str(loop_len) + ' Customer 
   Ids to go')

except TimeoutError:
  continue
  customer_price_at_date = customer_price_at_date.append(customer_id)
  db.connection.close()
  print('Error processing Customer Id ' + str(customer_id) + ' in loop ' + str(loop_len) + ' 
  Customer Ids to go')
```

The above code works and grabs the correct records from the MySQl db, but at present is pausing when a customer query within MYSQL has an empty return for the between date criteria.

All comments and advise greatly appreciated.

Kind regards

Duncan